# Mermaid - How to connect subgraphs in markdown?

Tags: markdown, mermaid

I'm using Mermaid in markdown. I can't figure out how to connect subgraphs.

Given the program below, I need to be able to connect one and two with an arrow.

````
 -  ```mermaid
    graph LR;
      subgraph one
        main---MainMenu
        MainMenu((MainMenu))---Game
        Game---Level
        Game---Player
      end
      subgraph two
        Screen
      end
      one-->two 
    ```
````

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, it's only possible to connect nodes, so you could do:

```
main-->Screen
```

Comment: Is there any update on this or this is the only way to do this.

Comment: no update on this, see https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/issues/197 and https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/issues/644 for any progression of this feature

Comment: OP can also update their original code from `graph` to `flowchart`

Comment: @amitsingh There is an update. See laktak 's answer.

Answer (score 16):

The beta now allows you to connect subgraphs:

```
flowchart TB
    c1-->a2
    subgraph one
    a1-->a2
    end
    subgraph two
    b1-->b2
    end
    subgraph three
    c1-->c2
    end
    one --> two
    three --> two
    two --> c2
```

https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=beta-flowcharts

Comment: Awesome.  This even works with ADO wiki, using the ":::mermaid  .... ::: " wrapper

Answer (score 2):

Updated, correct answer (hint: mermaid has been updated since previous responses to it works intuitively):

```
subgraph MySubGraph["Title of SG"]
    direction TB
    %% Can embed more here...
    MyNode
end
%% Can add connections above, or below like I prefer:
MySecondNode["Optional Node Title"]<-->MySubGraph
```